# Python Youtube-dl extracts invalid URL

Tags: python, youtube, pythonanywhere, youtube-dl

I'm writing simple Python/Flask script, which is suppposed to extract and redirect to URL of desired Youtube video for download. For this purpose I use youtube-dl module. In the code I create YoutubeDL object without any parameters.

```
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
ydl = YoutubeDL()
```

I'm developing the code locally and also I've deployed my code to [PythonAnywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com) (relevant snippet below) ...

```
def video(id):
    url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + id
    r = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)

    if 'entries' in r:
       video = r['entries'][0]
    else:
       video = r

    video_url = video['url']
    return flask.redirect(video_url)
```

... and it returns URL that looks correct at the first sight but it leads to blank page everytime.
The same code returns valid URL, that actually leads to video download when running locally.

This is how looks URL that works:

```
https://r11---sn-2gb7ln7k.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mm=31&ip=82.117.130.94&mn=sn-2gb7ln7k&pl=21&itag=22&signature=D73CFDE63BCE4359D57535A1478D1D9D65DA52AA.2C1AB3C70A9C95685DAFF5742D2D3ACE69306914&id=o-ALXi8_5fzzqW3bvJ-B9Yl2-hO927Vbfgx-ufVjNys1OI&mt=1459240812&upn=PhqlLYrRU3I&mv=m&ms=au&key=yt6&expire=1459262524&mime=video%2Fmp4&dur=4209.986&sver=3&ratebypass=yes&fexp=9408209%2C9416126%2C9416916%2C9417701%2C9420452%2C9422546%2C9422596%2C9423661%2C9423662%2C9424580%2C9427320%2C9427902%2C9429118%2C9429314%2C9431086%2C9431173%2C9432034&nh=IgphcjAxLnByZzAyKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&sparams=dur%2Cgcr%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&lmt=1458929174531688&ipbits=0&gcr=cz&requiressl=yes&source=youtube&initcwndbps=1297500
```

... and this is extracted URL of the same video, which leads to blank page:

```
https://r11---sn-p5qlsn7s.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?lmt=1458929174531688&ip=54.147.140.181&gcr=us&expire=1459262525&id=o-AH6rUZjQmWtR55nCdUd2VKG8QrZxZIgZ1aVaKp7Chc3s&upn=DDLzYOc4HBg&nh=IgpwcjAyLmlhZDI2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&pl=22&source=youtube&sparams=dur%2Cgcr%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&requiressl=yes&ratebypass=yes&key=yt6&mime=video%2Fmp4&fexp=9408506%2C9416126%2C9417368%2C9419452%2C9420452%2C9422596%2C9423661%2C9423662%2C9424132%2C9427143%2C9427364%2C9427902%2C9428422%2C9428710%2C9431439%2C9431464%2C9431860%2C9431952&ipbits=0&mn=sn-p5qlsn7s&signature=B71BF75C6BF798D49720F960F9AFF11E946382F0.8A17B35804BCBA5B0D0D2CA3C889B529A17AC9D9&mm=31&itag=22&sver=3&dur=4209.986&mv=u&mt=1459240330&ms=au
```

I have the same version of youtube-dl installed locally and hosted (2016.3.18).

Is there a way to control the format of URL on output (e.g. Youtube-dl options)? I could not find it in documentation. Or any other way to reformat URL to be valid?

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Could it be that your local instance and hosted instance are served different urls based on factors like location, time, ip etc. and they don't work from different location, time, ip etc. For example for me neither of those urls work. Parameters like 'expire' also hint at your urls being time variant.

Comment: Thanks, I am considering it. But I already tried another aproach: calling youtube-dl as a subprocess. Result is the same (URL is valid when running locally, when hosted isn't). Curious is the fact that callinag youtube-dl from bash accessible on PythonAnywhere hosting generates working URLs. That would disproves yours theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will partly answer myself - It seems that extracting video URL for download and actually downloading the video on 2 different machines won't reliably work ever (due to cookies, IP must be the same, ...) Documented [here](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#i-extracted-a-video-url-with--g-but-it-does-not-play-on-another-machine--in-my-webbrowser).